Proving that in $\Bbb R^2$ all orthonormal vectors rotate if a rotation is applied
Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a rotation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, by the definition of rotation given by Friedberg et al. Linear Algebra (Section 6.11), $T$ is a rotation $\iff$ $\exists\beta :\beta$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that, let $x_i \in \beta$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$ then $T(x_1) = \cos\phi x_1+ \sin\phi x_2$ and $T(x_2) = -\sin\phi x_1 + \cos\phi x_2$ and
if $y \in \mathrm{span}\{x_1,x_2\}^\perp$ $T(y) = y$.
Now how one can prove that in the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^2$ given, T a rotation defined like this, then $T(e_1) = \cos\phi e_1+ \sin\phi e_2$, $T(e_2) = -\sin\phi e_1 + \cos\phi e_2$, it's easy to do a proof of this using the matrix of change of basis and using some property of it knowing is orthogonal, in fact resolving  $QT(e_i) = AQe_i$ where $e_i = \{e_1,e_2\}$. Is there an easier way to do this and avoid the boring computations?

sorry i forgot, they are the standard ordered basis of $R^2$ $e_1 = (1,0), e_2 =(0,1)$

As far as I can understand, your question is: if $T$ satisfies "Friedberg's formulas" for some basis $\beta=(x_1,x_2)$ of $\Bbb R^2$, how to prove that it satisfies them for the canonical basis $B:=(e_1,e_2)$?
Actually, this only holds if $\beta$ has the same orientation as $B$, i.e. $\det(M_B(\beta))=+1$. If so, $M_B(\beta)=R_t:=\pmatrix{\cos t&-\sin t\\\sin t&\cos t}$ for some $t\in\Bbb R$, and $M_B(T)=R_t^{-1}M_\beta(T)R_t=M_\beta(T)$ because $M_\beta(T)=M_\phi$ commutes with $M_t$ (for any $\phi,t\in\Bbb R$).
If $\beta$ has the opposite orientation, $M_B(\beta)=R_tJ$ were $J=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$, and $M_B(T)=J^{-1}R_t^{-1}M_\beta(T)R_tJ=JM_\beta(T)J=JM_\phi J=M_{-\phi}$.
